# soap service on the top of rails3

Tags: ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, soap4r

hello is there a way to create soap service with rails3 application.
I have an old application with clients communicates via soap , and I need to create new analogue of service on rails 3 framework . I have no opportunity to change clients so I can't change API to REST or XML-RPC.

I found out that  actionwebservice was used for such things earlier , but what about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this latest forks from **actionwebservice** and **soap4r** gems:
https://github.com/roundlake/actionwebservice
https://github.com/bbhoss/soap4r

Comment: actionwebservice link is broken

Comment: seems that roundlake closed his fork. you can try other latest forks from https://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice that will work with yours rails version

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Savon](http://savonrb.com/), as their description says:

> Savon aims to be a simple but awesome abstraction of your SOAP service. Make sure to be
>   familiar with SOAP, WSDL documents and install soapUI before going Heavy Metal!

Comment: Savon is client library, I need server one

Answer (score 2):

As for now https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out is the best choice